# Find string in excel and replace output in another file

Tags: python, bash, powershell

Hello i need some assistance please as i am just getting started in my scripting journey.

File 1 is an excel output with a column named "new instance ID"

File 2 is existing file with a column named 'OLD instance ID"

What i would like to do is iterate through file 1 line by line,  grab the corresponding new instance ID, go to file 2, replace the OLD instance ID with the new instance ID.

any suggestion/simple bash or python, or power-shell script to get this done is appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a general overview of how you can solve this problem using Pandas dataframes in Python. Pandas has a function `read_excel` ([doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html))
where you can pass in your file and get a Pandas dataframe.

```
pd.read_excel(open('tmp.xlsx', 'rb'),
```

Do this for both files and you now have two dataframes that you can iterate through (using `iterrows`) ([doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html)).

```
row = next(df.iterrows())[1]
```

Finally, use `loc` ([doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)) to replace data in the first dataframe with your new data:

```
data.loc[5, 'column'] = 'new ID'
```

And write the file to csv ([doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html))

```
df.to_csv(index=False)
```

Hopefully, this should help you get started on a solution.